# Issue completing python code for a task

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Hello I recently started learning python and have searched for help throughout the internet for 12 hours trying to complete this task (it has been bugging me, lol) can someone please help me with the task or at least be able to tell me where I am going wrong with the code I have currently wrote so far.

Thank you, In Advance.

[Python Task Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBFD4.jpg)
[Code I have done so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASoz2.png)

Comment: If you want help, it is recommended to share the code, explain whats wrong and share  what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
while True:
    resp = input("Would you like some advice?")
    if resp not in ["Y", "N"]:
        print("Please enter Y or N only.")
    elif resp == "Y":
        print("Don't feed the trolls!")
        break
    else:
        print("Don't be silly, you definitely need advice!")
```

If you're using python 2, change `input` to `raw_input`.